# Can't stay logged in between subdomain and domain (using goutte or cUrl

Tags: php, curl, goutte

I'm using goutte to login to a restricted area with the purpose of retrieving files. The login is in a subdomain and it works, I can also follow links on the page after I login. But I need to use another address to search for the data and that's where I'm not logged in anymore.

Code I'm using:

```
$client = new Client();
$client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
$client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://subdomain.domain.com/subfolder/addr.jsp');
// this section works fine
$form = $crawler->selectButton('login')->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form, array('j_username' => 'XXXX', 'j_password' => 'YYYY'));
$error = $crawler->filter('td > font > strong')->count();
if ($error > 0){
  echo $crawler->filter('td > font > strong')->eq(0)->text();
} else {
  echo "no errors here<br />";
}

// this section shows I'm no longer logged in when I get the page
$addr = 'https://www.domain.com/portal/restricted_area';
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $addr);
// I use this to verify that the page shows the username = I'm logged in, but I always get the page that says I have to login
$loginProof = $crawler->filter('li.arearis > a')->count();
if ($loginProof > 0){
  echo 'We are logged in';
  // crawl more pages
} else {
  echo 'Not logged in';
}
```

Before using goutte I tried with cURL but with the same results. Cookies were being stored. I don't understand what I could be doing wrong. The same operation works fine if I do it by hand on the browser, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer this myself since I managed to solve the problem. There is nothing wrong with the code itself, I just needed to add some parameters to the address of the login page. That way, once logged in the server would redirect me to the right area of the website and from there I was able to stay logged in to perform further requests.